# Earth Engine Map view disappeared from Code Editor API. How can I bring it back?

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine, api, gui, user-interface

This question is about the interface on Google Earth Engine. I have been using it for several days without problem, however just today the map view disappeared. I can still bring up a small inset in the console but it is very irritating not having the default view. It's not minimized, I can't adjust it at all. Attached is a picture of what I see now:

[image]

Circled in red is where the button for expanding the map view should be. But it is gone. How do I bring it back?

Comment: Have you tried logging out/logging back in, restarting your browser, restarting your computer?

Comment: Yes, I even tried on another computer. The problem has just persisted. I'm using Windows 7 for what its worth.

Comment: Check out the help pages on panels and layouts. You might try using `ui.root.clear();`; see https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/ui_panels for more info.

Comment: @JepsonNomad I'm playing with the ui.root functions, but it doesn't seem to be doing anything. I've tried this with internet explorer and I'm getting the same problem as on chrome. It must be some kind of setting I've accidentally changed. Every process seems to run fine, I just can't view the map

Comment: I just had the same issue but I cannot solve it. Could you please tell me the steps you followed to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

Update: I was able to solve this problem by mousing over the toolbar adjuster for the left split plane and right clicking, going to inspect source. This brought up the html and identified the tool as a "handle. I then ctrl-f searched for "handle" in the html until I found the code for the vertical map split plane handle, which highlighted it. It was concealed behind the browser border somehow, but once highlighted I was able to selected it and adjust it with my mouse. I don't think this was working as intended.